# Python post request only words some of the time: website not sending back the correct response

Tags: python, python-requests

I have set up a Python script to download pdfs from a website, however, the code runs successfully at one point in time and then when I run the same code at another point in time, say a couple of hours later and it throws the following error:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

I'm assuming its because the server that I send the post request to isn't sending back the required response and when I try to convert the json response into a Python object it throws the error.

Only showing relevant parts of code. `"..."` represents an omitted section of code:

```
class BupaScraper(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.search_request = {
        "QuoteCriteria":{
            "FamilyType":"Single",
            "State":"NSW",
            "DateOfBirth":"1993-04-24T00:00:00",
            "PartnerDateOfBirth":None,
            "Frequency":"WEEKLY",
            "IncomeTier":"base tier",
            "IncomeTierCombined":None,
            "IsFromPrice":True,
            "HasEligibleChild":None,
            "IsCoupleOrFamily":False,
            "Age":25},
        "Excess":100,
        "PackageEntityName":"active-saver",
        "ProductType":1
        }

    self.all_covers = {
        "QuoteCriteria":{
            "FamilyType":"Single",
            "State":"NSW",
            "DateOfBirth":"1993-04-24T00:00:00",
            "PartnerDateOfBirth":None,
            "Frequency":"WEEKLY",
            "IncomeTier":"base tier",
            "IncomeTierCombined":None,
            "IsFromPrice":True,
            "HasEligibleChild":None,
            "IsCoupleOrFamily":False,
            "Age":25},
            "HealthNeedFilter":""
        }

    self.header = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': 'https://www.bupa.com.au/health-insurance/cover/active-saver',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': '330'
        }

def get_product_names_singles(self):
    #scrape product names
    combined_packages = []
    hospital_packages = []
    extras_packages = []
    post_url = 'https://www.bupa.com.au/api/cover/search'

    #Singles
    self.all_covers['QuoteCriteria']['FamilyType'] = 'Single'
    self.header['Referer'] = 'https://www.bupa.com.au/health-insurance/cover/singles'
    payload = json.dumps(self.all_covers)
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload, headers=self.header)
    output = r.json()
    #output = self.post_request(post_url,payload)
    package_names = []
    for item in output['Results']:
        for entity in item:
            if entity == 'EntityName' and item['EntityName'] not in package_names:
                package_names.append(item['EntityName'])

    for prod_type in package_names:
        if 'hospital' not in prod_type and 'extras' not in prod_type:
            combined_packages.append(prod_type)
        elif 'extras' not in prod_type:
            hospital_packages.append(prod_type)
        elif 'hospital' not in prod_type:
            extras_packages.append(prod_type)

    singles_products = combined_packages + hospital_packages + extras_packages
    print singles_products
    #return all packages
    return singles_products

... 
def post_request(self,url,data):
    self.data = data
    self.url = url
    req = urllib2.Request(self.url)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res = urllib2.urlopen(req,self.data)
    out = json.load(res)
    return out

def get_pdf(self):
    link ='https://www.bupa.com.au/api/cover/datasheets/search'
    directory = '/Users/U1085012/OneDrive/PDS data project/Bupa/PDS Files/'
    excess = [None, 0,50,100,500]

    #singles
    for product in get_product_names_singles():
        self.search_request['PackageEntityName'] = product
        print product
        if 'extras' in product:
            self.search_request['ProductType'] = 2
        else:
            self.search_request['ProductType'] = 1
        for i in range(len(excess)):
                try:
                    self.search_request['Excess'] = excess[i]
                    payload = json.dumps(self.search_request)
                    output = self.post_request(link,payload)
                except urllib2.HTTPError:
                    continue
                else:
                    break

        path = output['FilePath'].encode('ascii')
        file_name = output['FileName'].encode('ascii')
        #check to see if file exists if not then retrieve
        if os.path.exists(directory+file_name):
            pass
        else:
            ul.urlretrieve(path, directory+file_name)

    ...
```

How can I make the code more robust so that it runs all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I was very appreciative of the assistance given and I have incorporated those suggestions into my code, I believe the actual reason why I wasn't able to scrap the website is because my IP was being temporarily blocked for a period of time (looks like about 12 hours). This was the result of me constantly accessing the site during my scripts development (Its now finished) and the websites anti scraping policies. Obviously, there would be measures I could take to try and overcome these measures, like rotating IP addresses, rotating User Agents IDs, etc but I don't want to head into grey areas so I will settle for a limiting access because I will only need to scrap this site maybe three or four times a year when the information I need is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a time sleep right after sending the request, sometimes the response payload for your request are only incomplete, then when you try to convert in a JSON object it throws a error

```
import time
...
r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload, headers=self.header)
time.sleep(2)
output = r.json()
#output = self.post_request(post_url,payload)
package_names = []
```

Another thing you may want to try is surrond the json converter line with "try except" statement, to your script do not stop when a error is thrown:

```
import time
...
r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload, headers=self.header)
time.sleep(2)
try:
    output = r.json()
except:
    print('response error: ' + r.status_code)
    return False
package_names = []
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. This seems to have solved my issue. I will keep testing, but it appears as though at this stage to be working.

Comment: Ok, it seems to have stopped working again. Same error is being raised. Very frustrated with this. I can't seem to work out why it works sometimes and not others. You would think that if it was the website itself stopping scraping then it wouldn't work every time. I really hoping for some assistance with this.

Comment: A little more information: The response I'm getting back from the server is not what is expected, hence why  when I try to convert the json response to a python object it gives the error message: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded. Why would the server send me what appears to be garbled response?